# What do you think of an AWS based architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, amazon-ec2

I was reading through this article:

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2008/12/running-everything-on-aws-soocialcom.html

And I was wondering if this was good or bad. I am a fan of AWS myself, but I what to hear what the crowd thinks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is everything perfect in the Elastic World besides reliability. Obviously, the reliability and quality of service is dependent on the service provider and if the service provider is down you don't have anything to fallback on. I am a big proponent of AWS, but with the last two outages, I am now designing fallback on local data center servers in case of outages.

Comment: Indeed, I just had an EC2 instance lock on me...

Answer (score 0):

One of the main design decisions when designing a solution in AWS is to expect services to fail and implement mechanism to recover and if you need HA, then implement redundancy. Don't assume all the services to be reliable (Unless otherwise stated that they implement redundancy internally). Most of these problems are solved if you are using managed services such as Lambda, API Gateway, S3, Dynamodb & etc but if you are using services like EC2, then you have to design for HA, for example for EC2 using auto scaling and load balancing.

If you are interested to learn more refer [AWS Well-Architecture Framework](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS_Well-Architected_Framework.pdf) Whitepaper.